# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'first'

Tags: python, django

I want to filter post list on the basis of category using Django mptt.
Here is my code.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', null=True,
                              blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField('Content')
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                            related_name='children', db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'slug',))
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'apps/category_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post_list = Post.objects.filter(category=self.kwargs.get('category'))
        context['category_list'] = post_list
        return context
```

And urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<str:category>/',
         CategoryView.as_view(), name='category_filter'),
]
```

Here everything is imported correctly but when I entered URLs, for instance like the following
http://localhost:8000/category/first/
I am getting an error as the one shown in the image below.
[image]

Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching with category name then replace **category** with **category_name**

```
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs.get('category'))
```

Otherwise send category id in url

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't display any result.

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError
>   invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'first'

This exception is thrown when you mismatch datatypes.
Here, in your case, you're assigning the string value "first" to an integer variable.

Try to locate this and assign the index value in the form of Integer.

*reply if solved or unsolved!*